# MutableList map extension function outputs immutable List

Tags: kotlin

I want to map all my items in `MutableList` into other items:

```
(0..10).toMutableList().map { 1 }
```

What I have after is just `List`

```
(0..10).toMutableList().map { 1 }.toMutableList() //ok
```

Is there any `mapMutable` method? Or maybe this is wrong?

Comment: You mean you want to... map in place?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I want to get MutableList type after map { } fun

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

There's `mapTo` which let's you specify where to map the values into:

```
val origList = (0..10).toMutableList()
val mappedList = origList.mapTo(mutableListOf()) { 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `map` returns `List` and not `MutableList`, you have 2 choices:

```
val list = (0..10).map { 1 }.toMutableList()
```

or

```
val list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
(0..10).mapTo(list) { 1 }
```